# Weak convergence implies convergence in probability?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I'm striving to understand a proof from a paper.

Denote the symbol $\rightsquigarrow$ as a weak convergence, and $l^{\infty}(\Omega)$ as the space of bounded functions on a metric space $(\Omega, d)$.

Let $M_n$ be a sequence of random objects of $l^{\infty}(\Omega)$, which converges weakly to $M$, i.e. $M_n \rightsquigarrow M$.

Is it true that $\lVert M_n - M \rVert _{l^{\infty} (\Omega)}$ converges to zero in probability?

I know that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, but the converse is not always true.

If you need a reference, please read the last paragraph of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03012.pdf. (Alexander Petersen and Hans-Georg Müller, Fréchet Regression for Random Objects with Euclidean Predictors)

Thank you very much.

Caution : $\Omega$ is not a probability space in this question, instead it is a metric space.

P.S. I just highlighted the part. Thank you. Theorem 1.3.6 in van der Vaart(1996) is about the continuous mapping theorem.

[image: Feedback from the comment]

Comment: $\|M_n-M\|_{L^\infty }\to 0$ means that $(M_n)$ converges uniformly to $M$. So no, weak convergence doesn't implies uniform convergence. However, to answer the question in the title, yes weak convergence implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where in the last paragraph ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just edited. I meant that the norm converges to zero in probability.

Comment: Dear Romon, thanks for waiting.

Comment: Dear Surb, actually in fact, $M_n$ are not random respect to $\Omega$. Sorry for ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that $l^\infty(\Omega)$ is a normed space endowed with the norm $\|f\|_{\Omega} = \sup_{\omega \in \Omega}|f(\omega)|$.

Fix some bounded function $g:\Omega \to \mathbb R$.
Define the following map $\Psi$ from $l^\infty(\Omega)$ to $\mathbb R$:
$$\Psi:f\mapsto \sup_{w\in \Omega}|f(\omega)-g(\omega)|.$$

The following estimate holds for every $f_1,f_2\in l^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\omega \in \Omega$:
$$|f_1(\omega)-g(\omega)|\leq \|f_1-f_2\|_{\Omega} + \Psi(f_2),$$
hence $\Psi$ is $1$-Lipschitz, thus continuous.

It is known that $M_n \rightsquigarrow M$. Set $g = M$ and then by the continuous mapping theorem (Theorem 1.3.6 in van der Vaart and Wellner),
$$\Psi(M_n) \rightsquigarrow \Psi(M),$$
which rewrites
$$\sup_{w\in \Omega}|M_n(\omega)-M(\omega)|\rightsquigarrow 0. $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and it is surprising that you understood the question very quickly.

Comment: @d8g3n1v9 Part of my PhD is dedicated to Fréchet means and medians. Also, I spent countless hours studying the book by van der Vaart and Wellner.

Comment: Nice work. I am also working on these. I am indeed glad to meet you. Hope you graduate PhD and do whatever you want. I am alsp PhD, and having a littlebit of hard time….

Comment: @d8g3n1v9 Hang in there, it will get better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have a nice weekend.